# PowerShell: trying to print path of file if string found

Tags: powershell, if-statement, foreach

I am trying to print the path of a file if string is found.  Problem is if 1 file does not contain the string in a folder then I do not get any output.  Basically I am looking to see if a certificate epoch-time is within 30 days of expiration.  Below is my code:

```
$c = Get-Date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat %s
$epochtimes=[math]::Round($c)
$d = get-childitem C:\scripts\PALO\* -recurse | Select-String -pattern 
"expiry-epoch"
$e=$d -split "epoch"
$certtime=[double] $e[1]
$certexp = $certtime - 2592000

ForEach ($i in $certexp){
If ($certexp -le $epochtime) {
Write-Host $i
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a couple of assumptions since it isn't totally clear from your question what is going on.  Importantly, I've assumed you have a directory tree containing some text files each with a line in it like this:

```
expiry-epoch 1526854766.33933
```

If this is the case, then the following should display some useful information about the files:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\test" -File -Recurse |
        ForEach-Object {$threshold = [Math]::Round((Get-Date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat %s)) + 2592000} {
            $certEpochTime = ([double]($_ | Select-String -Pattern "^expiry-epoch (\d+\.\d+)$").Matches.Groups[1].Value)
            $certExpiryTime = (Get-Date "1/1/1970").AddSeconds($certEpochTime)

            New-Object -TypeName PsCustomObject|
                Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ExpiresSoon -Value ($certEpochTime -le $threshold)  -PassThru |                
                Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DaysUntilExpiry -Value ([Math]::Round(($certExpiryTime - (Get-Date)).TotalDays)) -PassThru |                
                Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CertExpiryTime -Value $certExpiryTime  -PassThru |
                Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CertEpochTime -Value $certEpochTime -PassThru |
                Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FilePath -Value $_.FullName -PassThru
        } | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

**EDIT:**
If all you need is the filename of any files with an `expiry-epoch` within 30 days, then this simplified version will do that:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\test" -File -Recurse |
        ForEach-Object {$threshold = [Math]::Round((Get-Date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat %s)) + 2592000} {
            $certEpochTime = ([double]($_ | Select-String -Pattern "^expiry-epoch (\d+\.\d+)$").Matches.Groups[1].Value)

            if($certEpochTime -le $threshold)
            {
                $_.FullName
            }
        }
```

Comment: What I am looking for is to print the filename or at least path of each file  where $certexp is within 30 days of todays date.

Comment: @user2214162, did you actually try my original example?  It does provide that information (and more).  In any case, I've added a simplified version that only provides the filenames.

Comment: I am afaird I do not understand, why is the $threshold in ForEach-Object?

Comment: It is in the `-Begin` block of the `ForEach-Object` (note the two `{..}` blocks after `ForEach-Object`), so is only processed once, before `ForEach-Object` starts dealing with the file objects coming through the pipeline.  You could move it to a line above and the result would be the same.  Get more info in the [ForEach-Object help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-6).