# Powershell script only looks at the first variable per file

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I have been working on creating a powershell script that looks for lines that contain the "expiry-epoch" for certificate expiration compare the values to a date 30 days from now and then send the hostname.  It looks for these lines through multiple files in 1 folder.  The lines are listed like:

```
set shared certificate TEST1 expiry-epoch 1533121779

set shared certificate TEST2 expiry-epoch 1525700960
```

The problem is if a file has multiple lines containing expiry-epoch, and the first line has a certificate that expires in some date longer than 30 days, such as 6 months or 3 months, then I get no output.  Below is my code, please let me know if there is something I am missing, since I am pretty much stumped.

```
$c = Get-Date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat %s

$epochroundedtimes=[math]::Round($c)
$epochtimes=$epochroundedtimes + 2592000

Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\PA-CERT1" -File -Recurse | 
    ForEach-Object {$epochtimes } {
        $epochMatch = $_ | Select-String -pattern "expiry-epoch"
        if ($epochMatch){
            $certexp = ([double]($_ | Select-String -pattern "expiry-epoch\(\d+)$").Matches.Groups[1].Value)
            if($certexp -le $epochtimes) {
                $_.Name
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Select-String -pattern "expiry-epoch" -AllMatches`? But you have two independant searches. I suggest trying to combine them else how would you know which statements are connected.

Comment: The problem is I need to convert the string to a number formal, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

With a better RegEx (positive lookbehind) `Select-String` will get you everything in one step:

```
Get-ChildItem -File | 
  Select-String -Pattern "(?<=expiry-epoch\s+)(\d+)" |
    ForEach-Object {
      "File {0} Line# {1} Expiry {2}" -F $_.FileName,$_.LineNumber,$_.Matches.Value
    }
```

Sample output based on above data:

```
File CERT.TXT Line# 1 Expiry 1533121779
File CERT.TXT Line# 3 Expiry 1525700960
```

Just do your calculation with `$_.Matches.Value`

**Edit** There is always another way:

```
Get-ChildItem -File |
    Select-String -Pattern "certificate (.*?) expiry-epoch (\d+)" | 
    ForEach-Object {
      "File {0} Cert {1} Expiry {2}" -F $_.FileName,
                                        $_.MATCHES[0].GROUPS[1].VALUE,
                                        $_.MATCHES[0].GROUPS[2].VALUE
    }
```

---

```
File CERT.TXT Cert TEST1 Expiry 1533121779
File CERT.TXT Cert TEST2 Expiry 1525700960
```

Comment: I believe I just got something with improvements, so I am using the $split method and I can give myself more output that is beneficial to this such as the certificate name as well as name of the file:foreach ($epoch in $epochMatch) {
$split=$epoch -split "expiry-epoch "
$certexp=[double] $split[1]
$split1 = $split[0] -split "certificate"
$certificate = $split1[1]

Answer (score 0):

I edited my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49762551/powershell-trying-to-print-path-of-file-if-string-found/49763413#49763413) to your question, so as to take into account of your new information.  This should get every occurrence from every file and display them in a easy to read table:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\richm\Desktop\TextFiles" -File -Recurse |
    Select-String -Pattern "expiry-epoch (\d+)" |
        ForEach-Object {$threshold = [Math]::Round((Get-Date ((Get-Date).AddDays(30)).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat %s))} {
            $certEpochTime = $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
            $certExpiryTime = (Get-Date "1/1/1970").AddSeconds($certEpochTime)

            New-Object -TypeName PsCustomObject|
                Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ExpiresSoon -Value ($certEpochTime -le $threshold)  -PassThru |                
                Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DaysUntilExpiry -Value ([Math]::Round(($certExpiryTime - (Get-Date)).TotalDays, 2))  -PassThru |                
                Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CertExpiryTime -Value $certExpiryTime  -PassThru |
                Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CertEpochTime -Value $certEpochTime -PassThru |
                Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FilePath -Value $_.FileName -PassThru |
                Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name LineNumber -Value $_.LineNumber -PassThru
        } | Sort-Object DaysUntilExpiry | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Example output:

```
ExpiresSoon DaysUntilExpiry CertExpiryTime      CertEpochTime FilePath  LineNumber
----------- --------------- --------------      ------------- --------  ----------
       True            3.95 21/04/2018 18:36:13 1524335773    cert3.txt          5
       True           14.92 02/05/2018 17:56:15 1525283775    cert1.txt          3
       True           14.92 02/05/2018 17:56:15 1525283775    cert1.txt          5
       True           14.92 02/05/2018 17:56:15 1525283775    cert2.txt          3
       True           14.92 02/05/2018 17:56:15 1525283775    cert3.txt          3
      False           39.92 27/05/2018 18:02:15 1527444135    cert1.txt          1
      False           39.92 27/05/2018 18:02:15 1527444135    cert2.txt          1
      False           39.92 27/05/2018 18:02:15 1527444135    cert3.txt          1
      False           99.95 26/07/2018 18:36:41 1532630201    cert2.txt          5
```